# What is the Svelte way to reference the DOM element created by an {#each} block when it is clicked?

Tags: javascript, svelte

I'm reactively loading elements using Svelte's `{#each}` functionality, like so:

```
{#each $items as item}
    <div>
       <Button on:click={someFunction}>{item.text}</Button> (*)
    </div>
{/each}
```

(*) a component which forwards its `on:click`

What I want to do is when someFunction is called by clicking the created item, reference the actual DOM element. I know you can reference the specific array item by passing the index to the function, but that gives me the array item, not a reference to the unique DOM element. How would one go about doing this?

Things I tried so far:

- `on:click={() => someFunction(this)}` → returns `undefined`
- `on:click={(el) => someFunction(el)}` → returns `undefined`
- `on:click={(e) => someFunction(e)}` → followed by using `e.target`, which does return the button that is clicked, but would need `.parentElement` to get to the div, which doesn't seem like a very Svelte way.
- `on:click={someFunction}` combined with `bind:this={anItem}` → which of course only returns the last created element in the `{#each}` block.

Comment: why do you need the dom element? The common approach in these frameworks is to prevent direct dom manipulation as much as possible.

Comment: What are you *actually* trying to achieve?

Comment: For example: the button in question is a modal which I want to have an open/close functionality. So, upon clicking itself I want it to toggle the class "open". However, using the class directive this results in all buttons/modals generated by {#each} to simultaneously toggle the class.

Comment: So if I understood correctly, you want only some items to open the modal, not all of the items in the `each` block, right?

Comment: Slightly different. Each item is a button and each button can have an open state, which should be triggered by clicking itself, the specific button within the `each` block.

Comment: With Svelte you don't need or want to be referencing elements the way you do with regular javascript. Svelte does that for you. Have the click handler set a variable and use Svelte syntax to display or not display your modal based on the state of that variable.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the parent div, a quick and dirty solution would be to just use an Array like this:

```js
<script>
   let itemsElements = [];
   const someFunction = (i) => console.log(itemsElements[i]); // <- this is your div
</script>
{#each $items as item, i}
    <div bind:this={itemsElements[i]}>
       <Button on:click={() => someFunction(i)}>{item.text}</Button>
    </div>
{/each}
```

A more elegant solution would be to wrap `<Button>` within a parent component and get the reference from there, through the [context API](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/context-api) for instance or a [slotted prop](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/slot-props).

Answer (score 0):

> the button in question is a modal which I want to have an open/close functionality. So, upon clicking itself I want it to toggle the class "open". However, using the class directive this results in all buttons/modals generated by {#each} to simultaneously toggle the class.

That just means you are using the wrong property. If you have multiple objects you need to store the state *per item* and then use that for the `class` directive.

E.g.

```html
{#each $items as item}
    <div>
       <Button on:click={someFunction}>{item.text}</Button>
       <div class="modal" class:open={item.show}>...</div>
    </div>
{/each}
```

Alternatively you can store the state in a separate list or a dictionary. You can also extract the content of the `{#each}` to a component which then can have a local state variable for the open state.